# Invalid Outside Procedure - new to coding

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I'm trying to hide certain rows of code dependent upon putting in a "password" into a cell in the same worksheet in Excel.
I'm not very savvy but here's what I've pieced together so far:

```
Sub HideData()

With Sheet2

If Cells("B1").Text = "password" Then Rows("2:500").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else: Rows("2:500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End With

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That error suggests that you have code outside Sub/End Sub statements. Have you omitted them from your posted code or not added them? Also, the clause after the Then needs to be on a new line.

Comment: I don't believe so, here's my full code I'm trying to run.
        Sub HideData()
        With Sheet2
        If Cells("B1").Text = "preserve" Then Rows("2:500").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else: Rows("2:500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        End With
        End Sub

Comment: Please add to your original post and format as code.

Comment: When that error comes up it will usually highlight the problem in the VB editor.

Comment: Yeah, VB highlighted the B1...

Comment: Oops, completely missed that. The syntax is wrong (see answer below) but wouldn't have expected that error to appear. Actually, I think you must have some stray text elsewhere as the B1 would produce a different error message.

Comment: Yes, the `Else` following the single-line `If` should have generated an "Else without If` compile error.  Once that is fixed (by moving the code after `Then` to a new line) you would get an "Invalid procedure call or argument" due to the `Cells("B1")`.  But nothing in your posted code should be generating an "Invalid Outside Procedure" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note the dots which tie the ranges to the sheet and without which the active sheet will be referenced - this won't have caused your error though):

```
Sub HideData()

With Sheet2
    .Rows("2:500").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (.Range("B1").Text = "preserve")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SJR, this worked. But I might have to try a new method I think based on what I need the excel sheet to do. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, that sounds like it is a different question.